# PHP - Remove the last directory from a URL

Tags: php, parsing, url

Lets say my URL is:

> http://www.example.com/news/media-centre/news/17/an-example-news-post/?foo=bar

I want to in PHP remove the last directory in the URL so I get:

> http://www.example.com/news/media-centre/news/17/?foo=bar

How do I do this while making sure I maintain any other URL parameters?

I've tried using this:

```
$url = parse_url( $url );
$url['path'] = str_replace( strrchr($url['path'], "/"), "", $url['path'] );
```

But the replace would cause issues if the last directory is also somewhere else in the path too.

Not to mention stitching the URL back together seems like a long way round...

Comment: [How to parse urls in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=parse+an+url+with+PHP) has been asked and answered multiple times before. The same holds true for [How to get the last segment in an URL Path](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=last+segment+in+url+path+php). Please use the search function before asking.

Comment: Have a go and see what doesnt work

Comment: @Gordon - I know how to parse a URL and get the last directory, but that's not what I'm asking. I'm asking how to reliably remove the last part directory in a URL.

Comment: @allen213 - Updated my question with what I've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$url = "http://www.example.com/news/media-centre/news/17/an-example-news-post/?foo=bar";
$info = parse_url($url);
$info["path"]=dirname($info["path"]);

$new_url = $info["scheme"]."://".$info["host"].$info["path"];
if(!empty($info["query"])) $new_url .= "?".$info["query"];
if(!empty($info["fragment"])) $new_url .= "#".$info["fragment"];
```

Comment: You need to add the trailing slash after dirname removes it - that is to match the requested example exactly.

Comment: Apache (and i believe other web servers, too) will add it back if the folder exists... (on request). so the request will still be valid..

Comment: @poncha Thank you for this. It is the dirname() function that I was after to trim off the last directory. I feel like a dipstick for not picking up on this function despite dealing with it on a regular basis.